# Difficulty in proving a function is convex

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $f(x)= -\sqrt[n]{(x_1x_2...x_n)}$ is convex in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

I have computed the gradient and elements of the hessian but the terms are awkward to simplify, much less prove that the hessian is positive semidefinite. Is there an easier way I am just not seeing or should i continue to do it with brute force?

Edit: can i do it by induction, starting from 1d, then assuming it works for kd$\ge$1 and so on?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps not a complete answer, but there's a half-page explanation in Steven Boyd's and Lieven Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization text (accessible in print and as a free of charge textbook online), on page 74, section 3.1.5, under the bold heading "Geometric mean.". It shows the geometric mean is concave, which means $-1$ multiplied by the geometric mean is convex. Apparently, the Hessian is computed, and it is shown to be negative semi-definite. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for vectors is applied.

Comment: @jrand I see, thanks for taking the time to look that up!

Answer (score 3):

The question was: Suppose a function is equal to negative one times the geometric mean. Why is that function convex?

The outline of the proof is as follows: First, prove the concavity of the geometric mean. Then, apply the relation between a concave function $g(x)$ and a convex function $-g(x)$ to show the convexity of $-1\cdot (\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^{1/n}$.

---

Showing the **geometric mean is concave**.

Suppose $f(x) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n}$, with $\textrm{dom }f = \mathbb{R}_{++}^n$.

A function, $f(x)$ is concave if two conditions are both met:

1. $\textrm{dom }f$ is convex.
2. The hessian, $\nabla^2f$, is negative semi-definite.

The domain of $f$ is convex because $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ is convex (shown by applying the definition of convex sets) and $\mathbb{R}_{++}^n$ is the direct or Cartesian product of a convex set (that convex set being $\mathbb{R}_{++}$). Hence, $\mathbb{R}_{++}^n$ is convex.

The hessian is shown as such:

$$f(x) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n}$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j} & = \frac{1}{n}(x_1x_2\ldots x_n)^{\frac1n - 1}(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{j-1}x_{j+1}\ldots x_n)\\
& = \frac1n (x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n)^{\frac{1-n}{n}}(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{j-1}x_{j+1}\ldots x_n) \\
& = \frac1n (x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n)^{\frac1n} \frac{x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{j-1}x_{j+1}\ldots x_n}{x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n} \\
& = \frac1n (x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n)^{\frac1n}(x_j)^{-1} \\
& = \frac1n (x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{j-1}x_{j+1}\ldots x_n)^{\frac1n} (x_j)^{\frac1n - 1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, calculating the diagonal terms,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_j^2} & = \frac1n \left(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{j-1}x_{j+1}\ldots x_n\right)^{\frac1n} \left(\frac1n - 1\right) x_j^{\frac1n - 2} \\
& = \frac1n \frac{1-n}{n}(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n)^{\frac1n} x_j^{-2} \\
& = \frac{(-1)(n-1)}{n^2} \frac{(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n)^{\frac1n}}{x_j^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, calculating the off-diagonal terms,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_j \partial x_k} & = \frac1n (x_j)^{\frac1n - 1} \frac1n (x_1 \ldots x_{j-1} x_{j+1} \ldots x_n)^{\frac1n - 1} (x_1 \ldots x_{k-1}x_{k+1}\ldots x_{j-1}x_{j+1}\ldots x_n) \\
& = \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{\frac1n} x_j^{-1}(x_1\ldots x_{j-1} x_{j+1}\ldots x_n)^{-1}(x_1 \ldots x_{k-1}x_{k+1}\ldots x_{j-1}x_{j+1}\ldots x_n) \\
& = \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{\frac1n} \frac{1}{x_k x_j}
\end{aligned}
$$

Recall the Hessian:
$$
\nabla^2 f = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_3} & \cdots \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2} & \cdots & \cdots \\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Replacing the known diagonal and non-diagonal terms,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla^2 f & = \frac{-1}{n^2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{n-1}{x_1^2} & \frac{-1}{x_1 x_2} & \frac{-1}{x_1 x_3} & \cdots \\
\frac{-1}{x_1 x_2} & \frac{n-1}{x_2^2} & \cdots & \cdots \\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix} \\
& = \frac{-1}{n^2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{n}{x_1^2} & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & \frac{n}{x_2^2} & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & \frac{n}{x_3^2} & \cdots \\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{x_1^2} & \frac{1}{x_1 x_2} & \frac{1}{x_1 x_3} & \cdots \\
\frac{1}{x_1 x_2} & \frac{1}{x_2^2} & \cdots & \cdots \\
\frac{1}{x_1 x_3} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
\right) \\
& = \frac{-1}{n^2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n}
\left(
n\cdot \textrm{diag}\left(\frac{1}{x_1^2}, \frac{1}{x_2^2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{x_n^2}\right) - \mathbf{q}\mathbf{q}^T
\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $$\mathbf{q} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{x_1} \\ \frac{1}{x_2} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{1}{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}$$

To show the hessian is negative semi-definite, we need to algebraically, the following:
$$
\mathbf{v}^T \left(\nabla^2 f \right)\mathbf{v} \leq 0 \qquad \forall \mathbf{v}.
$$
Then, replacing the Hessian,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{v}^T \left(\nabla^2 f\right)\mathbf{v} & = \frac{-1}{n^2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n} \mathbf{v}^T\left[ n \cdot \textrm{diag}\left(\frac{1}{x_1^2}, \frac{1}{x_2^2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{x_n^2}\right) - \mathbf{q}\mathbf{q}^T \right]\mathbf{v}\\
& = \frac{-1}{n^2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n} \left[ \mathbf{v}^T\cdot n \cdot \textrm{diag}\left(\frac{1}{x_1^2}, \frac{1}{x_2^2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{x_n^2}\right) \mathbf{v} - \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{q}\mathbf{q}^T \mathbf{v}\right]\\
& = \frac{-1}{n^2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n} \left[ n\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i^2 d_i - (\mathbf{q}^T \mathbf{v})^T \mathbf{q}^T \mathbf{v}\right]\\
& = \frac{-1}{n^2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n} \left[ n\cdot \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{v_i^2}{x_i^2} - \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{v_i}{x_i}\right)^2\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
where $d_i = \frac{1}{x_i^2}$ represents the diagonal entries of the matrix corresponding to $\textrm{diag}(\cdot)$, and $\mathbf{q}^T\mathbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{v_i}{x_i}$, which can be shown by listing $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ and performing the multiplication.

Consider the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for vectors:
$$
|\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{y}| \leq ||\mathbf{x}||_2 ||\mathbf{y}||_2
$$
Since both sides are greater than zero, the function $(\cdot)^2$ can be applied to both sides. This is a safe operation because $f(x) = x^2$ is monotone increasing in $\mathbb{R}_+$. Notice that $f(x) = x^2$ is not, in general, a monotone function.

$$
\begin{aligned}
|\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{y}| & \leq || \mathbf{x}||_2 ||\mathbf{y} ||_2 \\
\sqrt{\left(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}\right)^2} & \leq ||\mathbf{x}||_2 ||\mathbf{y}||_2 \\
(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y})^2 & \leq \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y}
\end{aligned}
$$

Suppose $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{1}$. $\mathbf{x}$ is an $n \times 1$ column vector consisting of ones. Suppose $$\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{v_1}{x_1} \\ \frac{v_2}{x_2} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{v_n}{x_n}\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then,
$$
\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{v_i}{x_i}\right)^2 \leq n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{v_i}{x_i}\right)^2
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
0 & \leq n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{v_i}{x_i}\right)^2 - \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{v_i}{x_i}\right)^2 \\
0 & \geq \frac{-1}{n^2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{\frac1n} \left[ n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{v_i}{x_i}\right)^2 - \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{v_i}{x_i}\right)^2 \right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Finally,
$$
\mathbf{v}^T (\nabla^2 f)\mathbf{v} \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow \nabla^2 f \preceq 0
$$
Hence, since it was determined the domain of $f$ was convex, $f(x) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n}$ is a **concave** function.

$-1\cdot f(x) = -1 \cdot \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{1/n}$ is **convex** because:

The domain of $-f$ is the same as the domain of $f$. The domain of $f$ was known to be convex, hence $\textrm{dom}(-f)$ is convex.

Secondly,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{x}^T (\nabla^2 f)\mathbf{x} \leq 0 & \Rightarrow (-1)\mathbf{x}^T (\nabla^2 f)\mathbf{x} \geq 0 \\
& \Rightarrow \mathbf{x}^T\left[(-1)\nabla^2 f\right]\mathbf{x} \\
& \Rightarrow \mathbf{x}^T \nabla^2\left(-f\right)\mathbf{x}\geq 0 \\
& \Rightarrow \nabla^2 (-f) \succeq 0.
\end{aligned}
$$

Notice that the Hessian of $-1\cdot f$ is $(-1)\cdot\nabla^2 f$. (The negative sign ``propagates'' through the derivatives and partial derivatives.)

In the last set of equations it was shown $(-f)$ is positive semi-definite. The domain of $(-f)$ is convex. Hence, $(-1)f(x) = -1\cdot(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^{1/n}$ is **convex**.